# .NET Application Memory usage grow over time, memory leak or not?

Tags: .net, memory

I wrote a .NET application where memory usage is growing over time. As a test,
I set it up to download 800 * 5K (average) size files and doing XML transform and using DTComcontroller to generate manifest, inside 1 hour with an interval of 15 Minutes. During a period of about 5 hours, memory usage grows from 35M to about 70M.

Not sure if this is normal or not. I'm already forcing it by doing

```
GC.collection();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

at end of each working circle just to make sure the memory are released in a timely manner.

I already make sure close filehandle, clear stream or other resources after used it. And some objects are just using local references inside a function and I assume they will be discarded at the end of local function and go away with GC.collction().

Also Memory Profiler (ANTS) shows that there are no objects with my application's namespace left at the end of each of the working circle, and no new objects with source code available left as well. The new instances of objects created during each working circle are basically called RuntimeModule, RuntimeAssembly, and DeviceContext. Doesn't looks like I could do anything about it?

This is basically my first application which are suppose to run 24/7 and I really don't know much about memeory leak. More likely than not, there are still problems with memory usage in my application. I just don't know where to look at this stage.

Also, I don't know it's related or not, I am using .net Trace/debug for keep a log. Guess it worth trying to turn off the log to see the memory usage grow.

Update: 
[image]
Dose it look like circle reference of sslstate and sslstream and also other Classes in the class Reference Explorer. Also not sure if that is a circle reference in ANTS generated graph, that means there is actually circle reference in my code somewhere?

I did a few changes by reusing the same object for XMLtransform and Manifest creation, and manually set each Object to null after finish used them in the end of working iteration. Now the memory are greatly reduced, still increase private memory usage as it is working, but much slowly.

I think for my particular case--create lots of objects inside a working circle, and every data is kept in a working thread. If I didn't explicitly release object references, let .NET GC doing that will lead to lots of memory used by the application as it is keep working most of the time, and GC may never get a chance to probably doing house keeping unless the application been manually closed, I have to do the object release much more manually.
@WeNeedAnswers:

```
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(dataFile);
            textReader.Read();
            doc.Load(textReader);
```

Comment: Apps should never need to call GC.Collect.  You are not necessarily helping and quite possibly making the problem worse.

Comment: If I directly using string in thread like Console.WriteLine("Hello world"), and the thread is keep running, will .NET release memory used by that string eventually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task Manager shows you the amount of memory belonging to the application that happens to be paged into real memory at the time (the working set). This is probably what you're seeing.

If you look instead at the "Private Bytes" used by your process, this should give you a better indication of the amount of memory used. This value doesn't change when the process working set is trimmed. There is more information in [this Microsoft KB article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140809100318/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/293215).

You can manually reduce your app's working set by using the Win32 API call [SetProcessWorkingSetSize](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.setprocessworkingsetsize)(GetCurrentProcess(), -1, -1).

This is what Windows will do anyway when the system runs low on memory, but controlling when this happens yourself lets you strip your .NET application's working set to its minimum size for investigation purposes.

BTW, [be very careful about calling GC.Collect()](https://web.archive.org/web/20160312013355/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, both you and Andrew have excellent answers. After days of research on memory usage in .NET, and I finally figure out at last that what cause the memory issue is the third party DTComController. The DeInitialise method for that object will consume lots of Process time and cause the memory couldn't be properly released A.K.A Memory leak. So I ended up without DeInitialise that object. And the Application running for days at the max load without a problem, still using more memory when running longer, which should take months for need to restart the application.

Comment: @PaulL thanks for posting that comment that shows there was indeed a leak. I am researching something similar and many people just say look at private bytes instead

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to deal with disposing of objects is the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface.  That is what allows you to use the `using` construct to ensure that objects are freed.  @Joe is right; in most situations, you should not call the garbage collector directly.

Comment: correct if I am wrong, but I think IDisposable interface is for writing your own class and make sure it will release resources properly? But since memory profiler tell me there is none class instances under my applications namespace left after each working circle, I assume that is not directly related to my memory usage/leak problem?

Answer (score 0):

> I wrote a .NET application where
>   memory usage is growing over time. As
>   a test, I set it up to download 800 *
>   5K (average) size files and doing XML
>   transform and using DTComcontroller to
>   generate manifest, inside 1 hour with
>   an interval of 15 Minutes. During a
>   period of about 5 hours, memory usage
>   grows from 35M to about 70M.

Is that a problem? If not (i.e. enough memory) that may be the reason. The GC only works when memory starts getting scarce. 70mb is also very low in general IMHO.

Comment: actually we are not sure it is a problem or not. We setup test so the application will be stressed almost as much as  the OS and the other application for doing the process could keep up. And after our application running during the weekend or overnight depending on how much we stress it, its memory usage will grow up to about 250M as shown in Task Manager. And then the application will keep giving error message something like "Could not load dll" (we are using DTCom object) and "cannot execute a program"  for every file to be processed and wouldn't seems to working after that.

Answer (score 0):

Nah not a leak, its a feature. Don't do the GC.Collect that is nasty. I would only worry about it being a leak if my test box was falling over because of lack of resources, not because the system was using more memory than I expected. The garbage collector doesn't run until it really has too. I don't think that the pressure your exerting on it is excessive enough for it to worry about it.

If your really concerned, push a big pile of data into your system at faster intervals and see what happens. If it can handle an extreme case in burst mode, then usually when you move over to the slow trickle it should handle it a bit more gracefully. Remember that its expensive to call the GC.Collect and so the Framework calls it when the algorithms decide that its necessary.

Are You enumerating the data in via a stream or just bunging it into memory. If the former than in my experience you get a consistant memory footprint. If the latter, depending on the size of the xml it may make it keel over.

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers, I've been add my code to do XML, I think that is at least part of the problem?

Comment: sorry I didn't understand that last comment. You added the xml code?

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with XML code I am using. You can see that as I am reading all the XML data into memory, so it using more memory than via stream?

Comment: It depends on your buffer settings, if you stream your data into your application it will take less memory if using large xml payloads. What do you do with the payload after it comes in, Xpath, XSLT, do you need to load the document in one large chunk. Or are are you processing the document piecemeal. If piecemeal element by element, attribute by attribute, do you need the XmlDocument object? if you can avoid the XmlDocument I would. Process the data sequentially. Depends on the application, but if its a feed of data you can usually buffer and feed in gradually.

Comment: I would treat the data as if its coming in via a DBReader and use the XmlTextReader to get the data into my appication where it can be used. It depends on the size of the xml payload and the application. Sometimes you can not avoid loading a document in memory all at once. The only case on the top of my head where I do load xml in memory all at once is XSL transformations.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out yesterday that as I am looking up a particular node in XML data, it is seems simpler to load the xmlDocument object and search for that node rather than search from a stream. As far as I make sure I release the memory used by xmlDocument object, memory shouldn't be a issue as I have to deal with lots of small xml objects rather than potential large XML data